# Rails 3 Model Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, rails-activerecord

I'm kinda stumped on how to relate some models I have. Was hoping for some pointers or ideas!

Let's say I have 3 models, named "MinorTeam", "MajorTeam", and "Game". Each game references two teams; but how do I designate whether it could be either a major or minor team?

```
has_one :team_1, :class_name => "MajorTeam"
# or 
has_one :team_1, :class_name => "MinorTeam"
```

The two team models are substantially different, so I couldn't simply add a major/minor flag to a Team model. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphic associations should work.  You might have to tweak things a bit to get it right, but by using them, the team classes don't have to be *anything* alike, apart from having games.

```
module Team
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :home_games, :class_name => "Game", :as => :team_1
    has_many :away_games, :class_name => "Game", :as => :team_2
  end
end

class MajorTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Team
end

class MinorTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Team
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team_1, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :team_2, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I'm assuming you meant for your `has_one` to be `belongs_to`, as `has_one` would mean that each team belongs to only one game, which seems like it might be incorrect.  If I'm mistaken, let me know.